# Golang dynamodb parallel scan returning same LastEvaluatedKey for all segment

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I am running a `golang` program that do `parallel scan` of `dynamodb` table. My ScanInput object is:

```
params = &dynamodb.ScanInput{
                TableName:         aws.String(tableName),
                ExclusiveStartKey: lastEvalKey,
                Segment:       aws.Int64(segment),
                TotalSegments: aws.Int64(TOTAL_SEG),
            }
```

I am getting error for all `segment` except first. For example if `totalsegment` is 4 than 3 will return below error:

```
ValidationException: The provided starting key is invalid: Invalid ExclusiveStartKey. Please use ExclusiveStartKey with correct Segment. TotalSegments: 4 Segment: 2
```

I checked by debugging that for segment that is having error `LastEvaluatedKey` is same as segment that is not throwing error.

I am calling the function that do scan as goroutine in waitgroup for each segment.

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(int(TOTAL_SEG))

    for i := 0; i < int(TOTAL_SEG); i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            Scan(int64(i))
            wg.Done()
        }(i)
    }

    wg.Wait()
```

Can anyone guide what is issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have never tried this in golang, but the name seems to say it all: ExclusiveStartKey.  If you're reusing an exclusive start key, it's not exclusive.  Try removing it from the struct.  Looking at the dynamodb documentation for parallel scans, they don't mention using an ExclusiveStartKey.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.ParallelScan

Comment: @ArloGuthrie Its there in link you share, in diagram of parallel scan ESk is exclusice start key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve the issue. Problem was for every segment for first scan I was passing `ExclusiveStartKey` as nil due to which starting point was same for every segment and it was returning same value of `LastEvaluatedKey`.

For first scan I did not pass ExclusiveStartKey for each `segment` and for subsequent scan for each segment I used `LastEvaluatedKey` return in previous scan in `ExclusiveStartKey`.

After carefully checking example at https://amazon-dynamodb-labs.com/design-patterns/ex2scan/step2.html I solve the issue.